# How to run Windows Driver Sample (Sample DMFT0)?

Tags: windows, camera, driver

I'm currently trying to build and run this sample from Microsoft's repository: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/avstream/samplemft0

The problem is that the project lacks information on how to run the sample. I've built it successfully but was not able to see any expected result when the camera app opens.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!